# FOSUser login error only in "prod"

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony-3.3

I have a fresh install of Symfony with fosuser and SonataAdmin. I try to show the users in the admin. I have followed the explainations in the Symfony doc, and everything is well if I go the `myapp/app_dev.php/admin`. I log in, go to the admin and see the users.

But, if I go the `myapp/admin`, I have an error when I try to log : "Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem."

I don't have any log in the prod.log file.

I am new using Symfony, so maybe there is a simple mistake... ?

Thanks for your help !

PS : Here is my log when I log with app_dev, maybe it can help ?

https://pastebin.com/cDvDR4XK

Comment: Is it showing any error in `app_dev` mode??

Comment: No, if I access admin via app_dev.php, I have no error and everything seems fine. I have no error in apache logs too.

Comment: Have you checked your configurations in app?? Once I've faced the same issue but I resolved by removing some deprecated functions from controller.

Comment: For the moment, all the code I have is generated by sensioGenerator. I haven't added things in controller, only changed the entities to fit my needs. My DB is up to date

Comment: Have you cleared the prod cache?

Comment: Oups... That's was the problem... I have said that could be a simple mistake ! :-P Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

When things like this happen, you should do at least:

- check symfony logs & apache/nginx logs
- check confs & database
- and obviously clear all caches